# Recommend a book about Java secure communication with x509

Tags: java, network-programming, ssl, x509

Can you recommend me a good book with code examples about Java secure network - how to  create server and client which use x509 certificate for encryption.

Best wishes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Java Network Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007218.do) - good start on Java networking in general.

[Java Security](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001575.do) - Java language security, also includes cryptography and networking.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend getting familiar with [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/), particular the [s_client](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html) can be useful when testing SSL connections to your server (SSL can use x509 client certs).

Comment: @benny23:The OP asks about Java specifically.Why does OpenSSL fits here?

Comment: Because I've found openssl increasibly useful when testing Java clients/servers, because if `openssl s_client` can connect against the custom-built Java server, then you know that the custom-built Java server is behaving correctly.

Comment: The OP wants to learn how to build a Java application with SSL.How does your answer help him do that?

Comment: In my view, understanding to use the `openssl` tools will provide a good background understanding on how certificates, keys and CAs tie together which is fundamental to building and testing a Java SSL application.  So it could prove useful in addition to a book (which are covered in another answer).